# Defining a Variable with Type Hint 'T' for int or float in Python Using Typing

Tags: python

I'm trying to define a variable in Python that can have a type hint of either `int` or `float`. I want to use Python's typing module to achieve this rather than using `Union`. Here's what I've attempted so far:

```py
from typing import TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T', int, float)

my_dict: dict[str, T] = {}
my_dict['key1'] = 42
my_dict['key2'] = 3.14
print(my_dict)
```

However, when I run this code, I receive a warning message that says:

"Type variable 'T' has no meaning in this context - Pylance"

I also tried another use case like this:

```py
CDType = dict[str, T]

def generate_dict() -> CDType[T]:
    return {
        'key1': 42,
        'key2': 3.14
    }
```

For this also, I get a warning:

"Expression of type "dict[str, float]" cannot be assigned to return type "CDType[T@generate_dict]"
"dict[str, float]" is incompatible with "CDType[T@generate_dict]"
Type parameter "_VT@dict" is invariant, but "float" is not the same as "T@generate_dict"

It seems like there's a typing issue here. Can someone please explain if I'm handling this incorrectly or if there's another way to define a variable with a type hint of 'T' for either `int` or `float` using Python's typing module?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `TypeVar` is for generic types, it's not a replacement for `Union`.  If you want to just avoid writing out the union type everywhere you can make an alias, i.e. `T = int | float`

Comment: I think `CDType[T]` fails because you have made the `CDType` generic by use of TypeVar, so when you do that the checker is expecting the supplied type arg to be a concrete type to make the generic specific, not the same TypeVar again

Comment: Ok. Thanks got it. 
Also I tried to find the resources to more about all these typing, protocol more advance concepts. Is there any recommended resources for this? (Official documentation is confusing)

Comment: I don't know, perhaps just pick up things little by little and it gradually becomes clearer. That's pretty much what I've done, though I had some familiarity with types in other langs before it became popular in Python, so sometimes I'm remembering that experience and can search for "the Python way" to express that. I find the site https://mypy-play.net/ is a handy way to quickly experiment with type checking.

Comment: Your code is working. **You must updating Python 3.12..0rc3**. Here is output  `{'key1': 42, 'key2': 3.14}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also discussed in the comments above.

In Python, TypeVar is a type hint used to represent a generic type variable. It's part of Python's type hinting system and is typically used when you want to indicate that a function or a class works with generic types but doesn't specify the exact types until later when you use the function or class.

You can create a type alias for your requirements. (or if you want to use TypeVar then you have to use it with function so that typing works as expected.)

Using type alias:

```py
T = int | float
```

So above program would be:

```py
T = int | float

my_dict: dict[str, T] = {}
my_dict['key1'] = 42
my_dict['key2'] = 3.14
print(my_dict)
```

And next part:

```
CDType = dict[str, T]


def generate_dict() -> CDType:
    return {
        'key1': 42,
        'key2': 3.14
    }


print(generate_dict())
```

You will have proper type annotation.

For more info:

- Using TypeAlias: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#type-aliases
- Using TypeVar: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#generics